# VB6 Gather updated URLs

Tags: vb6

I have a list of web addresses that I've already generated. The issue is, I believe the site uses php to generate their pages because when one of these addresses is navigated, the site adds a sub-directory to the address.

For example, if I navigate to...

```
http://www.wowhead.com/item=43
```

the address becomes...

```
http://www.wowhead.com/item=43/squires-boots
```

The sub-directory is different for every item number.

What I want to do is gather the url I'm redirected to for each address I've generated, and as there's a LOT of addresses (some 127,000), I'm looking for the fastest way possible.

Currently, I'm using the webbrowser control (wb)

```
Dim l As Long
Dim ff As Long
Dim strPerkText as String
Dim sPaths() As String
Dim lngTimer As Long
Const lngWait As Long = 5

strPerkText = OpenFile    'using a sub to get this data

sPaths = Split(strPerkText, vbCrLf)

ff = FreeFile

Open App.Path & "\ItemListURLs.txt" For Output As #ff
    For l = 0 To UBound(sPaths)
        lngTimer = Timer
        wb.Navigate2 sPaths(l)
        Do While wb.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            If Timer - lngTimer >= lngWait Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Write #ff, wb.LocationURL
        DoEvents
    Next l
Close #ff
```

lngWait is the amount of time I have to wait for wb to update with the new url, about 5 seconds per page, barring any errors. That means it would take roughly one week to do all the work with the way I have the program built now. I'm not sure if this can be accomplished any faster with either a different control, with API, or pure native code.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I've tested the Inet control. It has done the work in a small fraction of the time it would take webbrowser would, plus I don't have to worry about any errors that the site may throw. For others looking for something similar, here's the code I used:

Comment: URL rewriting hardly implies the use of PHP.  And don't be surprised if the site blacklists your entire IP subnet for hammering on them with this sort of thing.  One can only wonder what nefarious deeds you are up to trying to harvest URLs in this manner.  Hard to imagine this isn't against the site's Terms Of Use.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the Inet control. It has done the work in a small fraction of the time it would take webbrowser would, plus I don't have to worry about any errors that the site may throw. For others looking for something similar, here's the code I used:

```
Dim l As Long
Dim sPaths() As String
Dim b() As Byte
Dim strFileName As String
'OpenFile is a function that opens the specific 
'file with the list of URLs    
If strPerkText = "" Then
    strPerkText = OpenFile
End If
'split up the list
sPaths = Split(strPerkText, vbCrLf)
'progress bar - set to 0
pbrGo.Value = 0
'itterate through the list
For l = 0 To UBound(sPaths)
    'make sure there is a path to use
    If sPaths(l) <> "" Then
        'set the path to the Inet control
        Inet.URL = sPaths(l)
        'Retrieve the HTML data into a byte array.
        b() = Inet.OpenURL(Inet.URL, icByteArray)
        'GetFileName captures the end of the URL back to the last /
        strFileName = GetFileName(Inet.URL)
        'txtCollect.text contains the path where the files will be saved
        'adjust the filename to include the path and extension
        strFileName = txtCollect.Text & strFileName & ".txt"
        'Create a local file from the retrieved data.
        Open strFileName For Binary Access Write As #1
            Put #1, , b()
        Close #1
        'update progress bar
        pbrGo.Value = (l / UBound(sPaths)) * 100
        DoEvents
    End If
Next l
beep
MsgBox "Downloading Files Complete"
```